# GeoServer WPS vec:bufferFeatureCollection algorithm

Tags: geoserver, algorithm, wps

For GeoServer WPS plugin vec:bufferFeatureCollectinon function, what is the algorithm that support such function?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: After i install wps plugin in geoserver, i can use the wps vec:bufferFeatureCollection function, now I want to know the buffer implemention algorithm the function use.But I can't find related docuemnts that talk about it. it seems that i cannot paste image here,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortunately for you GeoServer is an open source project so you can go directly to the code base to check for implementation details that aren't covered in the documentation, in fact you can even update the documentation if you feel this is a missing item.

So the [`BufferFeatureCollection`](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/main/modules/unsupported/process-feature/src/main/java/org/geotools/process/vector/BufferFeatureCollection.java) process [calls (line 204)](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/4eb0214e73220c27350303b89832f11e139a9c50/modules/unsupported/process-feature/src/main/java/org/geotools/process/vector/BufferFeatureCollection.java#L204) the JTS Geometry `buffer` function. Since the [JTS docs](https://locationtech.github.io/jts/javadoc/org/locationtech/jts/operation/buffer/BufferOp.html) don't list the algorithm either, we can look at the [source code](https://github.com/locationtech/jts/) again, where a little digging leads us to [`OffsetCurveBuilder`](https://github.com/locationtech/jts/blob/master/modules/core/src/main/java/org/locationtech/jts/operation/buffer/OffsetCurveBuilder.java#L37) which uses an [`OffsetSegmentGenerator`](https://github.com/locationtech/jts/blob/master/modules/core/src/main/java/org/locationtech/jts/operation/buffer/OffsetSegmentGenerator.java#L37) to make the buffer which:

> Generates segments which form an offset curve.   Supports all end
> cap and join options    provided for buffering.   This algorithm
> implements various heuristics to    produce smoother, simpler curves
> which are   still within a reasonable tolerance of the    true curve.